# Could Carbon Monoxide be reduced by oxidising a more reactive metal?

Tags: electrochemistry, reduction-potential, carbon-family

After studying displacement at school, I wondered if it is possible to reduce the toxic gas of carbon monoxide to less harmful and more useful substances, like so:

Carbon monoxide + metal -> Carbon + metal oxide

Where the metal is of course more reactive than carbon, higher in the reactivity series, and so would displace it.

Is this chemically possible, or does it require too much energy? Forgive me if I appear foolish, but I just wonder if it could actually happen.

After researching extensively online, the main things which come up in searches are reduction of carbon dioxide, rather than carbon monoxide.

Comment: This must be possible with at least some metals, in that it won't require too much energy. But it will require too much money.

Comment: Oh right, that's interesting. Why would it be expensive? And would using something like aluminium work? As it's more reactive than carbon.

Comment: You don't have pure CO. You have a ton of CO2 and a little CO, and your metal is going to reduce both (at best).

Comment: Oh right. I was thinking more electrochemical reduction of something like smoke, which has a really high CO percentage in comparison to CO2. But would this fail too?

Comment: Smoke hardly ever has all that much CO, not to mention having a lot of O2. If you had pure CO some pretty interesting stuff can be made from it via reduction with alkali metals.

Comment: Magnesium is known to continue burning in CO2, producing carbon. Just guessing it could burn in CO as well, but the spontaneity should be calculated.

Comment: @Poutnik Well, $\ce{CO_2}$ is a lot more oxidizing (carbon at higher temperatures will burn exposed to it) than $\ce{CO}$. I have ruined many a yearly salary's worth of precision machined graphite parts to $\ce{CO_2}$ exposure, believe me.

Comment: @StianYttervik I am aware of CO2 being much better oxidant than CO. But as Mg reduce CO2 to C and not just  CO says something. As I say, it has to be calculated, or deduced from [wikipedia: Ellingham diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellingham_diagram#/media/File:Ellingham_Richardson-diagram_english.svg). Implying from the Mg burning temperature and the chart, Mg is able of reaction $\ce{Mg + CO -> MgO + C}$ above some 1850 deg C.

Comment: While possible, this way of reducing CO is not very practical. We already have good ways to reduce CO emissions in some circumstances. Vehicles use catalytic converters, for example, to oxidise CO to CO2 to reduce emissions, for example.